# Confusing thing about $\lim_{n\to\infty} nq^n$

Tags: calculus, limits

So we have : 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} nq^n , |q| < 1$$

Now lets transform this to:  $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{(\frac{1}{q})^n}$$
Then it says that $\lim$ is equal to $0$ because $(\frac{1}{q})^n$ is >> n, thats what confuses me, how can this be much greater than n, when 1/q is fraction and it goes to $0$ as it gets powered by n.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you divide by a very small number, is the result very small or very big?

Comment: If $\vert q \vert < 1$, then $\frac{1}{q}$ is still a fraction, but its modulo now greater than 1.

Comment: Ofcourse... Thanks alot i guess i am tired :)

Answer (score 3):

If $|q|<1$, clearly $|\frac{1}{q}|>1$. That to power n therefore blows up to infinity, and much faster than n.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is no need to use the $1/q$ thing. We have two ingredients here in the sequence $a_{n} = nq^{n}$. First is $n$ which is tending to $\infty$ and second is $q^{n}$ which tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ (because $|q| < 1$). In order to show that the sequence $a_{n} \to 0$ it is necessary to show that $q^{n}$ tends to $0$ much faster than $n$ tends to $\infty$ so that their product eventually tends to $0$.

To understand this we consider the ratio $$\left|\frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_{n}}\right| = \frac{n + 1}{n}\cdot |q| \to |q|\text{ as }n \to \infty$$ Let $r$ be a number such that $|q| < r < 1$. Then from the above limit we know that given any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a positive integer $m_{\epsilon}$ such that $$\left|\left|\frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_{n}}\right| - |q|\right| < \epsilon$$ whenever $n \geq m_{\epsilon}$. Now we choose $\epsilon = r - |q| > 0$. And then we get a positive integer $m = m_{\epsilon}$ such that $$\left|\frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_{n}}\right| < r$$ for $n \geq m$. Putting $n = m, m + 1, \dots, m + p - 1$ and multiplying the equations we get $$\left|\frac{a_{m + p}}{a_{m}}\right| < r^{p}$$ or $$|a_{m + p}| < |a_{m}|r^{p}$$ Since $0 < r < 1$ therefore $r^{p} \to 0$ as $p \to \infty$ and hence it follows that $$\lim_{p \to \infty}|a_{m + p}| = 0$$ which in turn means that $$\lim_{p \to \infty}a_{m + p} = 0$$ and therefore $a_{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

In fact we have proved a general result that

*If $a_{n}$ is a sequence such that $\dfrac{a_{n + 1}}{a_{n}} \to L$ and $|L| < 1$ then $a_{n} \to 0$.*